# Create DBus signal dynamically in python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, dbus

I've read some topics related to dynamically create python methods, and I followed their instructions, but it does not work. I do not know if it is because I use decorator `@` or something else.

The code is here, very simple.

When running this code, no error occurred, but when I use `D-feet`(A tool to check dbus informations), I could not find new signals I created.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.glib
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

import psutil

class EventServer(dbus.service.Object):
    i = 0

    @dbus.service.signal('com.github.bxshi.event')
    def singal_example(self,msg):
        """ example of singals
        """
        print msg

    def __init__(self):
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('com.github.bxshi.event', bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/com/github/bxshi/event')

    def create(self):
        self.i +=1
        setattr(self.__class__, 'signal_'+str(self.i), self.singal_example)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    eventserver = EventServer()
    gobject.timeout_add(1000,eventserver.create)
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have a typo: `singal_example` instead of `signal_example`
2. in your `create`-method you call `setattr` on the class. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you should simply emit the signal

This is the fixed example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.glib
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

#import psutil

class EventServer(dbus.service.Object):
    i = 0

    @dbus.service.signal('com.github.bxshi.event')
    def signal_example(self,msg):
        """ example of singals
        """
        print msg

    def __init__(self):
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('com.github.bxshi.event', bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/com/github/bxshi/event')

    def create(self):
        self.i +=1
        #setattr(self.__class__, 'signal_'+str(self.i), self.singal_example)
        self.signal_example('msg: %d' % self.i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    eventserver = EventServer()
    gobject.timeout_add(1000,eventserver.create)
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

After that you can connect to the signal:

```
# ...
bus = dbus.Bus()
service=bus.get_object('com.github.bxshi.event', '/com/github/bxshi/event')
service.connect_to_signal("signal_example", listener)
# ...
```

Comment: I do not want emit signals, The thing I want is create a new signal at runtime. I mean at first I may only have 1 signal, and after a request comes from other process, I will create a new signal for it.